# Two different JSON objects being returned from same URL?

Tags: android, json

I'm currently trying to send an URL to a server via my Android application, and I can send it fine, but it is returning a different JSON object (an access denied object), than if I send the same URL from my web browser. What could be causing this?

I have verified the URLs being sent are the same by outputting the URL I send in my app using Log.i and directly copy/pasting that into Chrome on my laptop.

The Two JSON Objects

```
// From app
{"status":{"status_code":401,"message":"Access denied"}}

// From web
{"nv43":{"id":23591778,"name":"NV43","profileIconId":22,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1396737099000}}

//URL being sent
https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/nv43?api_key=d96236d2-6ee3-4cfd-afa7-f41bdbc11128
```

Relevant Code:

```
package edu.appdesign.leaguestats;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class StatsActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textId;
    TextView textName;
    TextView textProfileIconId;
    TextView textRevisionDate;
    TextView textSummonerLevel;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stats_activity);

        final Button viewMasteries = (Button) findViewById(R.id.masteries);
        final Button viewRunes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.runes);

        viewRunes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(StatsActivity.this, RunesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        viewMasteries.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(StatsActivity.this, MasteriesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        GetStats stats = new GetStats();
        stats.execute();
    }

    class GetStats extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        private String api_key="d96236d2-6ee3-4cfd-afa7-f41bdbc11128";
        String region = MainActivity.region.toLowerCase();
        String name = MainActivity.name;
        String url = null;
        String encodedName = null;
        String encodedKey = null;
        String encodedRegion = null;
        String status = "status";
        String LOG = "JSONFetched";

        // JSON Node Names
        String TAG_ID = "id";
        String TAG_NAME = "name";
        String TAG_PROFILEICONID = "profileIconId";
        String TAG_REVISIONDATE = "revisionDate";
        String TAG_SUMMONERLEVEL = "summonerLevel";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            try {
                textId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
                textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                textProfileIconId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileIconId);
                textRevisionDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.revisionDate);
                textSummonerLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summonerLevel);
                encodedName = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
                encodedKey = URLEncoder.encode(api_key, "UTF-8");
                encodedRegion = URLEncoder.encode(region, "UTF-8");
                url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + encodedRegion + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + encodedName + "?api_key=" + encodedKey;
                Log.i("..........", url);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Get JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            Log.i("............", "" + json);
            JSONObject jb = null;

            try {
                jb = json.getJSONObject(encodedName);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            };
            return jb;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                // Storing JSON item to String
                String id = json.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = json.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String icon = json.getString(TAG_PROFILEICONID);
                String revDate = json.getString(TAG_REVISIONDATE);
                String sumLevel = json.getString(TAG_SUMMONERLEVEL);

                // Putting JSON data in TextViews
                String tmp = String.valueOf(id);
                textId.setText(tmp);
                textName.setText(name);
                textProfileIconId.setText(icon);
                textRevisionDate.setText(revDate);
                textSummonerLevel.setText(sumLevel);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getJSONFromUrl Code

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code that is creating the call?

Comment: Are you authenticating from the application when you are making the post?

Comment: very surprising indeed

Comment: this `jParser.getJSONFromUrl` is probably wrong. post the code from it. (very probably, seing how it looks like being from a quite known tutorial).

Comment: @njzk2 Code added. This being my first time working with JSON from URL, I did follow a tutorial to get the idea of how to handle it.

Comment: Try using HttpGet instead of HttpPost. You are passing parameters through your url and not posting anything.

Comment: yep. You code is doing a post, which is rejected. Change the `HttpPost` for a `HttpGet`, and in the future, stay away from that tutorials site.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I'll try to stick with the Android documentation from here on out. Are there any solid sources for guides/tutorials for Android?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html is a good place to start. SO also has a lot of common pitfall solutions as well. There are also app sample code in the sdk that is very good for starting a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it would be good to add a solution in case anyone looks here. Your code was using `HttpPost` to create your network call. However, your URL was expecting a GET, so you needed to change to `HttpGet`. For future reference, if you have any parameters in your url (ie. anything after a "?"), it is *usually* expecting a GET call.

Happy coding!

Comment: I'd like to point out that while this answer is correct for the main issue at hand (GET vs. POST), this answer is not entirely true. It's certainly possible to have query parameters on a POST.

Comment: You are correct. I may have been a little over-reaching with my comment at the end. While it is possible, it is usually not good design to have query parameters with a POST in an API.